# Alerts not appearing on registration page

Tags: joomla-3.x, registration, joomla-3.7

On my Joomla registration page, alerts and warnings are not appearing if users make a mistake in their email address or create a password which is too short. The page simply appears to refresh with no message to the user as to why their registration hasn't worked.

Furthermore, if I navigate to another page on my website, sometimes the alerts will appear there instead.  Here is the problem page:

[www.radiologycafe.com/create-an-account](https://www.radiologycafe.com/create-an-account/)

How can I correct this glitch.  Can anyone advise me on what to do?

**Note:** To replicate the issue, try registering using two different email addresses or create a password with fewer than 7 characters.

Comment: For me there seems to be some problem with caching. Is any cache option enabled on your site? Try to disable it and check if you get the same error again.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks - could you do me a massive favour and try again now - I think I may have fixed it but I'm not certain.  It may be related to SiteGround caching options :/

Comment: Now it works :) Yes SiteGround caching is sometimes a bad thing on some websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue for now.  It was a problem with the SiteGround Supercaching feature.  I disabled these within the 'System - jSGCache' Joomla plugin. Once I changed the SG Cache Status from 'enabled' to 'disabled', the alerts worked correctly.